# Unattach a JQuery drag and drop item from an area without deleting or hiding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a project that requires me to move divs into an area, have them resize themselves to the size of the area, and then snap to the area.

The issue I have is that when the bottom items are removed from the area, they "jump" up on the screen, as if they are compensating for the area the other items are taking up. I know this is not a good description, so I have a JSfiddle included.

To replicate, put 2 items into the area on the right, and then remove the bottom one. the item you are currently holding will move up on the screen when you take it out of the area.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Creator</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="drag-area">
            <div id="snaptarget" class="ui-widget-header">
            </div>

            <br style="clear:both">

            <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
                <p>A</p>
            </div>

            <div id="draggable2" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
                <p>B</p>
            </div>

            <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
                <p>C</p>
            </div>

            <div id="draggable4" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
                <p>D</p>
            </div>

            <div id="draggable5" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
                <p>E</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.drag-area {
  min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px auto 300px;
    grid-template-rows: 150px auto;
}

.draggable {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  font-size: .9em;
}

.ui-widget-header p,
.ui-widget-content p {
  margin: 0;
}

#snaptarget {
  width: 173px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-column: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

jQuery/JS:

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".draggable").resizable();
  $("#snaptarget").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(e, ui) { //use add class to add tabs maybe?
        var $item = ui.draggable;
        $item.appendTo($(this)).css({
            margin: 0,
            position: "relative",
            top: 0 + "px",
            left: 0 + "px",
            width: $(this).width() + "px"
        });
    },
    out: function(e, ui){
        var $item = ui.draggable;
        var position = $item.offset();
        var x = position.left;
        var y = position.top;
        $item.css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: y + "px",
            left: x + "px"
        });
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9pk6zt5a/

The issue appears to be that each item calculates it's x and y position relative to the area when it is attached, which is what I wanted to do in order for it to snap to the top. Dragging it out changes its position to absolute, to prevent it from interfering with other items in the area.

Ideally, the best way to solve this would  be to somehow detach it, and revert it to its form just before it is attached to the area. I can not find a way to do that.

I have tried to fix it by using offset, and changing the positioning, but neither worked.

As side note, is there an easier way to accomplish something like this in react? I don't know any react, but I am willing to learn if it makes this any less frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Try reverting the process by dropping the item back into the .drag-area similar to this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".draggable").resizable();

    // Make the area droppable so that you can drop back the items
    $('.drag-area').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            if(!ui.draggable.parents().first().hasClass('drag-area')){
                ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
            }
        }
    });

    $("#snaptarget").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (e, ui) { //use add class to add tabs maybe?
            var $item = ui.draggable;
            $item.appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style').css({
                top: ui.offset.top + "px"
            });
        },
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L932c0wr/7/